# .NET 5 Project Template?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-5

I updated Visual Studio using the VS Installer, I have the modules .NET 5 runtime and .NET SDK, my NET Core projects can be targeted towards .NET 5 but I don't have a .NET 5 template project in the VS project selection window. Is this intended or am I missing something?

Comment: For clarification, "my NET Core projects can be targeted towards .NET 5".. so you're familiar with SDK-style projects and have successfully built your project targeting `net5.0`, right?  So, your question and issue is specifically inquiring why there isn't a .NET 5 template project included in VS after the download and installing of these 'modules'?

Comment: Yes, my question is specifically about the project template. I do not think is a good idea to have to change the target when I create a new NET Core, it can lead to errors

Comment: @Oslier .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. There's no separate `.NET 5 Project Template`. Either create a .NET Core project directly or change an existing project's target to 5

Comment: .Net 5 is not .net core 5 - its a new .net - quite different from .net core. They have a historical lineage and that's it. .Net 5 needs to have project templates for sure.

Comment: Please reopen this question. Does Microsoft intend that we not have templates for .Net 5? Do they intend that we have to make a different app or library and then rip the guts out of it like what we have to do to convert a UWP Blank App template to a home baked CoreWindow template?

Comment: @Oslier Take a look at this [post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-cli-templates-in-visual-studio/) about templates. They do some rework at the moment in order to make it easier to provide templates for _Visual Studio_ and for the _CLI_ as well. For the time being you can enable _**Show all .NET Core templates in the New Project dialog**_. I did that in order to get _Framework Selection_ (from .NET Standard to Core to .NET5) when creating new projects.

Answer (score 4):

According to Microsoft:

> New application development can specify the net5.0 target framework
> moniker (TFM) for all project types, including class libraries.
> Sharing code between .NET 5 workloads is simplified in that all you
> need is the net5.0 TFM.

I have been catching up with all the preview releases of Visual Studio 2019. Its version currently is 16.9 Preview 1, and I still cannot find the .NET 5 Project Template or even change the target framework to .NET 5 in the project properties. It might be fully compatible in the official release, perhaps.

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five

Comment: this is not an answer. it is a comment. And actually, the low value question isn't going to have a definitive answer.  No one in this community (as it relates to any ontopic matter) can explain to the OP 'why' (at this moment in time) there is no .NET 5 template project after they updated VS to include .NET 5 runtime and SDK, nor whether that is an expectation they should have or have had in the first place.

Comment: in regards to your own uncertainty in this 'answer' - there is no requirement (or reasoning) to have a project template, and project properties GUI is not a means to determine compatibility or otherwise.  To do as the cited quote specifies - just add\designate the tfm in `<targetFrameworks>` attribute in your project file.  The whole matter of whether it will work depends upon associated .config, .prop and .target files associated to MSBuild and whether they were changed\targeted following installing the SDK and runtime.

Comment: @Brett Caswell "there is no requirement (or reasoning) to have a project template" - lol. It's funny because we have project templates and we expect them. I want to make a .net 5 application and there is no project template currently that gives me that.